# Using multiple wildcard parameters with arcpy.ListFeatureClasses

Tags: arcpy, list, wildcard

I know there has to be a way to do this but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do so. I would like to create a list of feature classes to perform operations on however, I want to have the list contain feature classes which have 2 separate and distinct file name identifiers. The code would look something like:

```
FCS = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("X_*" OR "*_Y")
```

I know OR is incorrect however, is there some way to do this without having to re write code to work with the second wildcard. Thanks for helping gout, i know there is a selection method in the Select By Attributes which allows for multiple wildcard use using the OR statement.

Comment: The wildcard parameter only takes a string as input, so short of running `ListFeatureClasses()` twice (which could potentially be too slow for large directories, it's best to pass no wildcard and then just filter through the result after.

Comment: Paul, that is exactly what the list comprehension answer below does - it runs through the list and filters it based on the if statement.

Comment: @dklassen, OP is looking for FC that end in "_Y", not start. You can wildcard that against a GDB, but not shapefiles with your code.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add the two together, they are just lists.

```
FCS = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("X_*") + arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*_Y")
```

To eliminate duplicates:

```
FCS = set(arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("X_*") + arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*_Y"))
```

Comment: This works also, thanks @Jason Sheirer, using startswith and endswith works for me in a file GDB. When I altered the script I was using to work with an SDE, it didn't work for some reason. The method you mentioned does work in SDE.

Answer (score 6):

You could approach it a bit differently:

```
import arcpy
import os

arcpy.env.workspace = 'c:\temp'
fcs = [fc for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses() if fc.startswith('X_') or os.path.splitext(fc)[0].endswith('_Y')]
```

Comment: This won't really work unless you are in a GDB. The extension is returned for shapefiles.

Comment: This should work for any feature class within your set workspace.  Including shapefiles - why wouldn't we want an extension returned?

Comment: Because you can't wildcard with this against ending characters - which is what OP looks to be doing.

Comment: @Paul Modified - thanks for the correction.  I didn't see the "_Y" part.

Comment: A bit nitpicky, but you should use `os.path.splitext()`. The shapefile could have a period in the name. +1

Comment: thanks @dklassen, the method described above works well. I'm really glad I now don't have to have run 2 ListFeatureClass().

Comment: @standard No problem, thank Paul as well, he help me out with my slight errors too!

Answer (score 1):

This scripts specifies multiple wildcards in a list `cases` []. Than it loops over unique cases, listing desired feature classes 'arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()'. Each selected feature class is that added to the new list of feature classes using '.extend'

```
# Create a list of the wildcards 
cases = ["X_*", ""*_Y""]

# Create empty list to store all selected files
fcs= []

# Loop through files to select files following multiple wildcards
for case in cases:
    fc = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(case)
    # Insert the fc to the list
    fcs.extend(fc)
```